# Word processing performance: ArrayList.toArray() or StringBuilder.split()

Tags: java, performance

I am reading a newline-separated text file into a `String`-array.

Since I know the delimiter will always be `\n`, I should be able to append each word to a StringBuilder, then split it using the delimiter.

Simply put, which method should I use and why?

**Method A:**
1. Create an ArrayList (or another more suited Collection)
2. Append each row to the list
3. Return `list.toArray()`

**Method B:**
1. Create a StringBuilder
2. Append each row to the builder
3. Return `builder.split("\n")`

Comment: You'd better return a List<String> from the method rather than an array. But whatever you use, most of the time will be spent in reading the file, not in processing the String/List. Reading a file from a disk is very slow compared to transforming things in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it makes much of a difference, the `toArray` method is most likely faster as there is less `String` processing. The `split` would have to process the entire data with regex; the `toArray` method would just need to loop over the `Collection`.

If you amend your method **B** so that you don't read the file line-by-line into the `StringBuilder` but use [`Files.readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to get the entire file as a `String` then `split` you will probably find performance more or less identical.

If you have Java 8:

```
final Path path = /*some path*/
final String[] lines = Files.lines(path).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Note, your method **A** can be improved by using `Files.readAllLines`:

```
final String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).
    toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably very little difference. I don't think you're working with very large files anyway, so it shouldn't matter. You can profile the different ways if you really are interested in it, but the choice you make is quite irrelevant.

I would go with the `ArrayList` way if it was my choice, since concatenation just for splitting afterwards seems redundant.

Comment: Relatively large (>100.000). I agree ArrayList is prettier and looks a bit more robust, just curious regarding performance. :)

Comment: Well, a LinkedList would save you the underlying array resizing then. 100,000 lines is not even relatively large though.

Comment: ArrayList have same array limit but it's very large (Integer.MAX_INT), if your list is really so long maybe a LinkedList is what you need.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno The issue is that ArrayList will resize its internal array as it grows (unless you initialize it with a large enough size at creation). I already recommended LinkedList, since it doesn't require the resizing (the max length of an array isn't really an issue here).

Comment: I benchmarked the process using ArrayList and LinkedList and, surprisingly, LinkedList took an average of 1,5-2x the time of ArrayList (did multiple runs).

Comment: I hope you know how to benchmark properly (JVM warmup, multiple runs in the same process, etc.), otherwise you can get all sorts of results if doing simple timing with `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If you know the approximate amount of lines beforehand, you can initialize the `ArrayList` with a suitable capacity to reduce the amount of array resizes.

Comment: Not really surprising. LinkedList is almost always slower than ArrayList: instantiating nodes takes time, and navigating from nodes to nodes, not necessarily in contiguous memory locations, is much slower than iterating over an array, using contiguous memory locations.

Comment: @krystah yeah, `LinkedList` is usually faster is you are add/removing elements to/from the middle using an `Iterator` and if the `List` is very large. Otherwise `ArrayList` is significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, if you read a file in this format:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Why not just read it and save in the same time?

Something like:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String line; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null; )
{
    lines.add(line);
}

System.out.println(lines);
```

And you will have `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]` in your `lines` `List`.

Comment: The result has to be a String array. It's size can not be known until all elements are processed, thus elements can not be added while processing.

Comment: `lines.toArray()`; --- About "not be added while processing" i need for info.